# Did we always have to register to download the Java 5 JDK, or is this new Oracle fun?

Tags: java, download, java-5

I could swear that just a couple of months ago I downloaded a copy of the **Java 1.5** SE JDK and I did not have to give them information on my first born.  Today, I had to go through the register-and-we-will-send-you-a-link-someday dance. I have not received the link yet, so I thought I would ask about it here.

- What is special about the **Java 5 JDK**?  I can get Java 6 just by clicking, is this a stick to get us to migrate to Java 6?
- Am I just not remembering doing this before?
- What marketing genius thought this would be a value add for Java?  "If we make them sweat for the JDK they won't just delete it willy-nilly the next time?"
- Does everyone picture the people designing systems like this as mustache twirling Snidely Whiplash clones like I do?
- Did I just miss the link for the Secret Squirrel route to the download page?

Finally, I am in the U.S. so I should not have to worry about export restrictions.

Any thoughts?

P.S. Did I mention I am trying to get the **Java 5 JDK** ;-)

Comment: Oracle tries to hide older versions from regular users so they are always getting the latest Java (for good reasons, of course). As for power users and developers, we are smart enough to dig it out (as you can see below). You can get pretty much any Java vers[i](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/)on, **even 1.1**, if you just l[o](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/)ok ha[r](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/)d enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 5 has passed its sell-by date on [October 30, 2009](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/eol.policy.html). That means that support is only available as paid business support, which of course requires registration.

You shouldn't really be using Java 5 anymore, unless you're committed to some large, complex installation, in which case you should seriously consider that paid business support - I guess the automatic registration page is intended to drive home that point.

<s>**Edit:** You can still download Java 5 without registering via the [technology archive](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/).</s> *(Not any more, it also requires login now.)*

Comment: I don't think just downloading the JDK really counts as support, I am not asking for anything from them.  As for using Java 6, I would be happy to, but even smaller projects will die under constant version churn.  As it is I am working on a patch, what you are suggesting is kind of extreme for what will be a little jar file swap in the end.

Comment: @Ukko: Java 5 is *six years old*, that's hardly "constant version churn". But it's still available for free, see edited answer.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! for the technology archive link, that worked. As for version churn, Java 5 has had 22 releases since then, one every 3 months or so, the other components are also constantly changing. It adds up, in most cases it doesn't matter but in some it does.  (Honestly, the JDK is not one that I worry about myself but it gets thrown in with the other libraries in teh pot.)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the technology archive now requires a login too.

Comment: @aclark: I will point out though that as of this writing, if you sign up for a new account, it lets you proceed with the download even without clicking the "verification" link. So you could sign up with dummy information. I'm not *advocating* it, just mentioning. :-)

Comment: It is year 2014 now and there are still a lot of applications using Java 5 and 6 because they simply work.

Comment: @Mukus: and the vast majority of them will also simply work on Java 8.

Comment: Changing url from http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-windows-x64.exe to http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-windows-x64.exe
seemed to enable my download for java 6 sdk without registering. (/otn/ to /otn-pub/)

Comment: The information by @Lauw still works - to find the link in first place check the html source of the page and then do the replacement.

Comment: @Lauw is right about the download. It works, but first you have to accept Oracle's license agreement (cookies should be saved).

Answer (score 3):

Go [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/widget/jdk6.jsp). Click "Download" (left). Then click `Skip this Step` (it's tiny on the bottom of the new widget that appears when you click "Download").

EDIT:
For JDK 5, go [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index_jdk5.jsp), click "Download" and then just click `Continue to Download` without entering anything in those fields.

Comment: That is for Java 6, I am having trouble getting Java 5 or 1.5.

Comment: It looks like you can get the version with J2EE and the version with Netbeans to work that way but the vanilla JDK takes me to a page titled "Java SE Registration Download (JDK 5.0 Update 22)".  What am I missing?

Comment: I see now. It *does* ask for registration. It says *The Java SE release that you requested has already announced its End of Service Life (EOSL)* which means @Michael Borgwardt is probably right.

Comment: The funny thing is I set up a VM with it in the last 6 weeks, so if that is the case then they only just changed it after EOLing it last year.

Answer (score 1):

There's a link that says: "Skip this Step"

Comment: I only saw that link for Java 6, where is it on the Java 5 download page?  I would love to get it back up and running.

Comment: Not anymore. Perhaps soon we won't be able to skip the "recommended" Ask toolbar installation, either...